# Custom action goal: "has no attribute" error

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a custom action called *TakePosition.action* with the following data :

```
#goal
int64 x
int64 y
int64 z
string position
---
#result
bool completed
---
#feeback
string report
```

When I try using my **TakePositionActionGoal** in my client.py script, I get an error saying :

```
  File "/home/sisko/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sweepbot_tools/msg/_TakePositionActionGoal.py", line 122, in serialize
    buff.write(_get_struct_3q().pack(_x.goal.x,
_x.goal.y, _x.goal.z)) AttributeError: 'TakePositionActionGoal' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Here's my client.py script :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

import rospy
from sweepbot_tools.msg import TakePositionAction, TakePositionActionGoal

import actionlib

def setPosition():
    client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('sweepbot_movebase_server', TakePositionAction)

    client.wait_for_server()

    goal = TakePositionActionGoal()
    goal.goal.x = 7
    goal.goal.y = 7
    goal.goal.z = 7
    goal.goal.position = ''

    client.send_goal(goal)

    client.wait_for_result()

    return client.get_result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        rospy.init_node('sweepbot_movebase_client')
        result = setPosition()
        rospy.logdebug(result)
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        print("program interrupted before completion", file=sys.stderr)
```

The porpose is to create pose data which I can pass to my custom action server which would calls move_base with the recieved pose.

Clearly there is an **x** attribute in my action definition. I don't understand what the souce of this error is.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375990/custom-action-goal:-%22has-no-attribute%22-error/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2021-04-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-12**:
I've updated the title of your question to better reflect the problem you were having.

Seeing as action servers are *servers*, using the words "not responding" makes it seem there is something wrong with your server, while you're having problems writing the client script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> goal = TakePositionActionGoal()
> ```

I believe that should actually be:

```
goal = TakePositionGoal()
```

Refer also to the [Writing a Simple Action Client (Python)](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Action%20Client%20%28Python%29) tutorial:

> ```
> # Creates a goal to send to the action server.
> ```

```
goal = actionlib_tutorials.msg.FibonacciGoal(order=20)
```

where they do the same.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0